# Load jQuery from another dir

Tags: javascript, jquery

## The symptoms

If I have jQuery in root dir -- js files in child dir say jQuery is undefined.

If I have jQuery in child dir -- js files in root dir say jQuery is undefined.

If I have the same jQuery lib in both places — all works fine.

## Possible solution

Suppose I'd keep jQuery in a child dir. Than I guess I have to "notify" js files in the root dir of the path to jQuery. Here's one of the root dir js file:

```
/**
 * select a different prefix for underscore
 */
$u = _.noConflict();

/**
 * make the code below compatible with browsers without
 * an installed firebug like debugger
if (!window.console || !console.firebug) {
  var names = ["log", "debug", "info", "warn", "error", "assert", "dir",
    "dirxml", "group", "groupEnd", "time", "timeEnd", "count", "trace",
    "profile", "profileEnd"];
  window.console = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; ++i)
    window.console[names[i]] = function() {};
}
 */

/**
 * small helper function to urldecode strings
 */
jQuery.urldecode = function(x) {
  return decodeURIComponent(x).replace(/\+/g, ' ');
};

/**
 * small helper function to urlencode strings
 */
jQuery.urlencode = encodeURIComponent;

/**
 * This function returns the parsed url parameters of the
 * current request. Multiple values per key are supported,
 * it will always return arrays of strings for the value parts.
 */
jQuery.getQueryParameters = function(s) {
  if (typeof s == 'undefined')
    s = document.location.search;
  var parts = s.substr(s.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
  var result = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    var tmp = parts[i].split('=', 2);
    var key = jQuery.urldecode(tmp[0]);
    var value = jQuery.urldecode(tmp[1]);
    if (key in result)
      result[key].push(value);
    else
      result[key] = [value];
  }
  return result;
};

/**
 * highlight a given string on a jquery object by wrapping it in
 * span elements with the given class name.
 */
jQuery.fn.highlightText = function(text, className) {
  function highlight(node) {
    if (node.nodeType == 3) {
      var val = node.nodeValue;
      var pos = val.toLowerCase().indexOf(text);
      if (pos >= 0 && !jQuery(node.parentNode).hasClass(className)) {
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.className = className;
        span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(val.substr(pos, text.length)));
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(span, node.parentNode.insertBefore(
          document.createTextNode(val.substr(pos + text.length)),
          node.nextSibling));
        node.nodeValue = val.substr(0, pos);
      }
    }
    else if (!jQuery(node).is("button, select, textarea")) {
      jQuery.each(node.childNodes, function() {
        highlight(this);
      });
    }
  }
  return this.each(function() {
    highlight(this);
  });
};

/**
 * Small JavaScript module for the documentation.
 */
var Documentation = {

  init : function() {
    this.fixFirefoxAnchorBug();
    this.highlightSearchWords();
    this.initIndexTable();
  },

  /**
   * i18n support
   */
  TRANSLATIONS : {},
  PLURAL_EXPR : function(n) { return n == 1 ? 0 : 1; },
  LOCALE : 'unknown',

  // gettext and ngettext don't access this so that the functions
  // can safely bound to a different name (_ = Documentation.gettext)
  gettext : function(string) {
    var translated = Documentation.TRANSLATIONS[string];
    if (typeof translated == 'undefined')
      return string;
    return (typeof translated == 'string') ? translated : translated[0];
  },

  ngettext : function(singular, plural, n) {
    var translated = Documentation.TRANSLATIONS[singular];
    if (typeof translated == 'undefined')
      return (n == 1) ? singular : plural;
    return translated[Documentation.PLURALEXPR(n)];
  },

  addTranslations : function(catalog) {
    for (var key in catalog.messages)
      this.TRANSLATIONS[key] = catalog.messages[key];
    this.PLURAL_EXPR = new Function('n', 'return +(' + catalog.plural_expr + ')');
    this.LOCALE = catalog.locale;
  },

  /**
   * add context elements like header anchor links
   */
  addContextElements : function() {
    $('div[id] > :header:first').each(function() {
      $('<a class="headerlink">\u00B6</a>').
      attr('href', '#' + this.id).
      attr('title', _('Permalink to this headline')).
      appendTo(this);
    });
    $('dt[id]').each(function() {
      $('<a class="headerlink">\u00B6</a>').
      attr('href', '#' + this.id).
      attr('title', _('Permalink to this definition')).
      appendTo(this);
    });
  },

  /**
   * workaround a firefox stupidity
   */
  fixFirefoxAnchorBug : function() {
    if (document.location.hash && $.browser.mozilla)
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        document.location.href += '';
      }, 10);
  },

  /**
   * highlight the search words provided in the url in the text
   */
  highlightSearchWords : function() {
    var params = $.getQueryParameters();
    var terms = (params.highlight) ? params.highlight[0].split(/\s+/) : [];
    if (terms.length) {
      var body = $('div.body');
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        $.each(terms, function() {
          body.highlightText(this.toLowerCase(), 'highlighted');
        });
      }, 10);
      $('<p class="highlight-link"><a href="javascript:Documentation.' +
        'hideSearchWords()">' + _('Hide Search Matches') + '</a></p>')
          .appendTo($('#searchbox'));
    }
  },

  /**
   * init the domain index toggle buttons
   */
  initIndexTable : function() {
    var togglers = $('img.toggler').click(function() {
      var src = $(this).attr('src');
      var idnum = $(this).attr('id').substr(7);
      $('tr.cg-' + idnum).toggle();
      if (src.substr(-9) == 'minus.png')
        $(this).attr('src', src.substr(0, src.length-9) + 'plus.png');
      else
        $(this).attr('src', src.substr(0, src.length-8) + 'minus.png');
    }).css('display', '');
    if (DOCUMENTATION_OPTIONS.COLLAPSE_INDEX) {
        togglers.click();
    }
  },

  /**
   * helper function to hide the search marks again
   */
  hideSearchWords : function() {
    $('#searchbox .highlight-link').fadeOut(300);
    $('span.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
  },

  /**
   * make the url absolute
   */
  makeURL : function(relativeURL) {
    return DOCUMENTATION_OPTIONS.URL_ROOT + '/' + relativeURL;
  },

  /**
   * get the current relative url
   */
  getCurrentURL : function() {
    var path = document.location.pathname;
    var parts = path.split(/\//);
    $.each(DOCUMENTATION_OPTIONS.URL_ROOT.split(/\//), function() {
      if (this == '..')
        parts.pop();
    });
    var url = parts.join('/');
    return path.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, path.length - 1);
  }
};

// quick alias for translations
_ = Documentation.gettext;

$(document).ready(function() {
  Documentation.init();
});
```

This is weird: I don't see any path specifications in this script. However — see symptoms...

**Edit**:

Here's how the js scripts are loaded

```
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="_static/jquery.js"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="_static/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_static/js/jquery-fix.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_static/underscore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_static/doctools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_static/bootstrap-3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_static/bootstrap-sphinx.js"></script>
```

`_static/jquery.js` is a copy of `_static/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js`. When first line is commented `doctools.js` complains, and when the second is commented — `jquery-fix.js` complains. `jquery-fix.js` is a single line:

```
var $jqTheme = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

## Screenshots

When first line commented:

[image]

When second line commented:

[image]

Comment: When you include scripts in JS they are global unless you use a module loader or restore their global space pollution to the original state. I don't understand your issue at all.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Neither do I. But the symptoms are reproducible.

Comment: Please reproduce them and show them to us then. There are lots of sites you can use to do this - the simplest one IMO is http://jsfiddle.net , make sure you include the least amount of code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: How are you loading the jQuery library in your document?  Are you using relative file paths?

Comment: @JPDurham: I do: see edit.

Comment: What happens if you move `_static/js/jquery-fix.js` to `_static`?

Comment: try removing the `//@ sourceMappingURL=` line from your jquery code file or modify it to `//# souceMappingURL=` instead and see if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `.noConflict(true)` in `jquery-fix.js` solves it. Now everything works as one would expect: nothing depends on where the files are stored.